# How to uninstall Firebase functions emulator after installing it with "firebase init"

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I installed the Firebase Functions and Firestore emulators in my project with `firebase init > emulators` but now realize I don't need the Functions emulator any more so I'm trying to delete it.

How can I uninstall an emulator so that the `firebase emulators:start` command doesn't try to start it by default?

I tried the following but `firebase init > emulators` continues to show that the functions emulator is still enabled (green dot) and `firebase emulators:start` continues to start the functions emulator by default if I don't include the `--only firestore` flag.

- I reran `firebase init > emulators` and deselected functions

  - This didn't do anything
- I manually removed the entry from `firebase.json`

  ```json
  "emulators": {
    "functions": { // <-- I removed this block
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
  ```
- I cleared the emulator cache from `~/.cache/firebase/emulators`
- I removed the `functions` block from `firebase.json` just to see if that was triggering it.

  ```json
  {
    "functions": { // <-- I removed this block
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run clean",
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
      ],
      "source": "functions"
    },
    "firestore": {
      "rules": "firestore.rules",
      "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
    },
    "emulators": {
      "firestore": {
        "port": 8080
      },
      "ui": {
        "enabled": true
      }
    }
  }
  ```

After doing all of the above, `firebase emulators:start` still tries to start *functions*. I wondered if it might be because the firestore emulator depends on the functions emulator but if that were the case I don't know why it would let me run the firestore emulator alone with `--only firestore`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I deleted the Function directory from **node_modules** and I removed the functions block from **firebase.json** too.

I fixed it just running npm install firebase again.

Comment: Removing a service from `firebase.json` did the trick for me.

Comment: Reinstalling firebase cli was not necessary for me. Removing from firebase.json and deleting the functions folder was enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Cloud Functions in your project, you should remove the "functions" folder from your project directory as well.

Also, suggest that you file a bug for this on [the firebase-tools GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools).  The fact that the functions emulator runs without configuration in firebase.json feels like a bug, and it didn't used to work that way.

Comment: Thanks I filed a bug. I do want to use functions, just don't need to run the functions emulator